# SwiftUi Load Local Json Data

Tags: json, swift, swiftui

I actually learning SwiftUi, and at the moment i don't get into my problem.

I try to load Json Data from my local Json File !

I have searched many many many Post but nothing really helped me, that is why i have chosen to make this post.

I show you how i possible tried it.

Path: Data/test.json

```
[
    {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "",
    "trade_name": "",
    "short_name": "",
    "test":  "",
    "test1": "",
    "test2": "",
    "test3": "",
    "test4": "",
    "test5": "",
    "test6": "",
    "test7": "",
    "test8": [],
    "test9": "",
    "test10": "",
    "test11": "",
    "test12": ""
    },
]
```

Path: App/DataLoader.swift

```
import Foundation

public class DataLoader {
    
    @Published var contentData = [JSONData]()
    
    init(){
        load()
        sort()
    }
    
    func load(){
        if let fileLocation = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test", withExtension: "json"){
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileLocation)
                let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                let dataFromJson = try jsonDecoder.decode([JSONData].self, from: data)
                
                self.contentData = dataFromJson
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func sort(){
        self.contentData = self.contentData.sorted(by: { $0.id < $1.id})
    }
}
```

Here in this File i add the variables.
Path: App/JsonData.swift

```
import Foundation

struct JSONData: Codable {
    
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var trade_name: String
    var short_name: String
    var test: String
    var test1: String
    var test2: [String:String]
    var test3: [String:String]
    var test4: String
    var test5: String
    var test6: [String:String]
    var test7: String
    var test8: [String:String]
    var test9: String
    var test10: String
    var test11: String
    var test12: String
    
}
```

I didn't set the Display yet but i want it in a List.
In my ContentView.swift File i would load the Data from that Json File !

Path: App/ContentView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Home()
                .navigationTitle("Test Interface")
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct Home : View {
    let data = DataLoader().contentData
    
    var body: some View {
        data[IndexPath.row].id
    }
}
```

When i did it like that, it shows some Errors.

Return type of property 'body' requires that 'Int' conform to 'View'

Instance member 'row' cannot be used on type 'IndexPath'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

Regards

CreatingBytes

Comment: it should be ```Text("\(data[IndexPath.row].id)")``` insdide the body view.

Comment: If i do this it show up following error.
Instance member 'row' cannot be used on type 'IndexPath'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

Comment: Yes because there is no IndexPath you need ForEach View but for now just pass any number for testing.

Comment: How can i manage this exactly ? Can i simply make a ForEach ? Like ForEach(1...10){ Text(data[name])}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SwiftUI is not UIKit, there are no index paths.

The `body` property of a `View` must return *some View*, nothing else.

- First of all adopt `Identifiable`

  ```
  struct JSONData: Codable, Identifiable { ...
  ```
- Then adopt `ObservableObject` in `DataLoader`

  ```
  public class DataLoader : ObservableObject {
  ```
- You have to observe the data in the root view, replace `ContentView` with

  ```
   struct ContentView: View {
       @StateObject var data = DataLoader()

       var body: some View {
           NavigationView {
               Home(data: data)
                   .navigationTitle("Test Interface")
                   .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
           }
       }
   }
  ```
- In `Home` hand over `data` and use `ForEach`

  ```
   struct Home : View {
     @ObservedObject var data : DataLoader

     var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            ForEach(data.contentData) { item in
               HStack {
                   Text(item.name)
                   Spacer()
                   Text("\(item.id)")
               }
           }
        }
     }
  }
  ```

Alternatively replace `ForEach` with `List` to get a table view

I highly recommend to watch the videos of WWDC 2019 and 2020 about SwiftUI

Comment: Right thanks for you're help i really appreciated it. Nothing errors are showing but, i don't see any List Entry. I replaced the ForEach with an List Item. But both versions are not showing anything.

Comment: There is something wrong with your JSON decoding. `test2` and 3, 6, 8 is the wrong type.